# Joomla: How to detect if a column in our table exists and if not add it to the table

Tags: mysql, joomla

Our Joomla plugin now requires a new column on its table.

So, for existing installations (older versions) that will install the new plugin version, we need to detect the absence of this column "linkimageflag" on the database and then ADD it.

I tried several code snippets but it always shows this error:

"1054 Unknown column 'linkimageflag' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT linkimageflag FROM nk6px_test_plugin"

This is the last code that I tried:

```
$querycol = "SELECT linkimageflag FROM #__test_plugin";
$database->setQuery($querycol);
$colresult = $database->query();
```

//    $rows = $database->loadObjectList();

```
if (!$colresult) {
    $querycol = "ALTER TABLE #__test_plugin ADD linkimageflag varchar(10) NOT NULL";
    $database->setQuery($querycol);
    $database->query();
}
```

What is the proper code to do such action?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$columns = $db->getTableColumns('#__your_table_name');
if(!isset($columns['columnName'])){
   // run your query to add column
}
```